# Under which conditions the linear combination of two Wiener processes is still a Wiener process.

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $\{W^{(1)}_t , t\ge0 \} $ and $\{W^{(2)}_t , t\ge0 \} $ be independent Wiener processes.
Find all constants for which $\alpha W^{(1)}_t +\beta W^{(2)}_t, t\ge0$ is Wiener process.

I already saw the answers to the questions

- [linear combination of two Wiener processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289648/linear-combination-of-two-wiener-processes?rq=1)
- [With what a and b this IS a Wiener Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148187/with-what-a-and-b-this-is-a-wiener-process)

But did not understand how they were resolved. I will be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W_t := \alpha W_t^{(1)} + \beta W_t^{(2)}$. The covariance function of a Wiener process is $t \wedge s$ (and it is unique for gaussian processes). Thus we want to solve
$$\Bbb E [W_t W_s] \overset{!}{=} t\wedge s$$
The left hand side can be transformed to $\alpha^2 (t\wedge s) + \beta^2 (t\wedge s)$.
Thus $W_t$ is a Wiener process iff $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$